# How to pass data in nested components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I wonder how to pass data in nested components.
I'm making an app using react-native with react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist.

Based on what I understand about the conception of redux, even though it is consist of nested components, can get or update state from store.
However, I'm doing that only pass data as props from parent component to children components.
I guess it is not correct usage of redux because the more depth is deeper, the more I have to call functions of parent components.
Sounds weird, right?
If you see my code, then you would understand what I'm talking about.

Here's my code.

[image: Edit redux question]

**UPDATED**
For example, code structure is like bellow.
If I want to call action in grandChild component, Should I go up to parent Component?

**parent.js**

```
...

getData = async () => {
    await Actions.func();
}

render() {
    return (
        <Parent>
            <Child data={data} getData={this.getData}/>
        </Parent>
    );
}
```

---

**child.js**

```
...
childFunc(){
    this.props.getData();
}

<Child>
    <GrandChild grandChildFunc={this.childFunc}/>
</Child>
```

---

**GrandChild.js**

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.childFunc();
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Example</Text>
        <View>
    );
}
```

**I want to figure out of redux cause reducer is called twice now, but I have no idea what happen here.**

If you give any advice, it would be helpful for me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the right way. But I'm doing with components:

- Reuse UI, dynamic with different data -> Pure Component. Pass `props` from parent
- Just use for 1 logic/data -> Component. Connect to store

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I think your answer is not what I'm looking for. I updated my post.

Answer (score -1):

which function get fired twice? be more expecific based on your code please, after that the comunity could be more helpful. i think that if you mixed arrow functions with normal functions you probably get any unwanted function fired. keep in mind that when a Component is mounted for first time, the React Lifecycle call the render method twices.

in your grandChild Component you call the childFunc() after the component is successfully rendered. and maybe in your child Component you call the function for first time without knowing it. so please be more especific and show the exactly part of your code you are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update my code. By the way, Is there any problem in the structure above code? I mean this structure 'parent <= child <= grandchild' to call whatever I want to call function.

Comment: What if deeper than the example, whenever I want to dispatch action, should I pass function from grand grand child to parent?

Comment: if you want to dispatch any action you should create that action on the actions.js file and then pass the action/function as props with the help of redux. Every time the action is called, a playload will be dispatched from the reducer to the component you will. you are also able to recive the data / playload in your dessired Component as props.